# Last request date Sybase

Tags: sybase

I'm trying to find a way to get last request date for a given SPID. I have 2 SPID's on `Waiting Command`; there is no transaction open for either SPID.

```
SELECT @@version

> Adaptive Server Enterprise/12.5.3
```

Comment: Sybase ASE 12.5.x has no last request date in the standard system tables.  `select * from sysprocesses;` will show a fair amount, but not the last time a request was made.  :-(

Comment: Ok Ty ..............  :(